# HTML bookmark links not working

Tags: html, hyperlink, bookmarks

I'm working on an HTML page with bookmark links (a href/a id) and when I validated the page on W3C the validator told me that whitespace wasn't allowed in links and that I should replace it with %20 and so I did with a PHP function. After doing that my bookmark links stopped working. Then, instead of replacing the whitespace with %20 I tried replacing it with an empty string ("") and thus removed the whitespace altogether and my bookmarks started working again. Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some PHP code might be helpful but I think it's enough if you use `urlencode()` function. It will auto-magically convert any string to match the URL standards.

Here's the [REFERENCE](https://www.php.net/urlencode).